# Find all template tags in a PHP string?

Tags: php, regex, templates

I have an activity event log in my app that logs every actions a user does in the app.

The action records have an `event_type` to tell what type of event it is.

There will be a page to view this activity log/stream as well.

My app also allows users to create and use custom plugins and in the plugins they can define there own `event_type` and then create activity events using there `event_type` from there plugin code.

The `activity_type` is stored in it's own database table and has a column `template` which will be used to store the text that will be shown everytime this `event_type` is shown on the activity log/stream page.

For example

> Jason Davis created a Bookmark for the website StackOverflow at
>   http://www.stackoverflow.com

For the above output we need to store the values for these items below inside the actual Activity Event record:

- Jason Davis
- StackOverflow
- http://www.stackoverflow.com

The name of user will be in a table column but the other data could be different types for each event_type.

For this reason on the `activity_events` DB table I have a column named `entity_meta_json'

`entity_meta_json' will allow an`activity_event` record to store any key/value of extra data for the event.

Then back on the Activity log/stream page where we will build our nice HTML view of the events.  I can take the `template` column from the events `event_type` and replace the template tags with any matching key/values in the `entity_meta_json' column.

The final result is that each Event type can have its own HTML view on the event log/stream page and plugin developers can easily add new event_types and build there template for there event_types as well and register events in there own plugin and pass in any extra data that is required by there template!

#### Some code...

This code takes a JSON string from the database and converts it into an array and then replaces a template string with template tags with the array key/values....

```
// simulate getting JSON data back from the Database
$dbJsonString = '{"submitdate":"2-16-2016","metakey2":"metavalue2","metakey3":"metavalue3"}';

// convert database JSON string back into an Array
$jsonArray = json_decode($dbJsonString, true);

// template string text with template tags to be replaced by matching data in $jsonArray
$templateString = '<strong>Date Submitted:</strong> {{submitdate}} {{tag_that_has_no_key}}';

foreach ($jsonArray as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value) && $value != '') {
        $templateString = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $value, $templateString);
    } else {
        $templateString = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', '------', $templateString);
    }
}

echo $templateString;
```

The output

```
Date Submitted: 2-16-2016 {{quotenumber}}
```

---

#### The Problem...

Now in the demo it works great, except that if the template has template tags that the array does not have a matching Key for, then the template tag simply shows up in the final result in tag format.

I would like to instead replace template tags that have no matching key with an empty space.

Because the way it works now, it iterates over each key in the array to find replacements for so those missing keys are never going to see the template tag that has no key in array.

The template will always remain the same with those tags in it in the DB.  The plugin developer though will call a function to add new event records and there data might be missing some of the template tag keys.

An idea,

If I can also parse the template string and grab all the template tags in the string, I can then compare that with the array of data values the user passes in and any missing key in there array I can add that key to there array and set the value to empty which would make the template tag be detected and replaced when the other tags are.

#### The Question...

So my question would be how I might detect all template t ags in the format of `{{tag_name_here}}` in a streing and put each one into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~{{([^}]*)}}~', function ($m) use ($jsonArray) {
    return isset($jsonArray[$m[1]]) ? $jsonArray[$m[1]] : '';
}, $templateString);
```

The advantages are:

- no need to loop into `$jsonArray`, since possible keys are tested with `isset` for each `{{...}}` in the string.
- the string is parsed only once.